# What is Upstream First Policy

Tags: architecture

Why it is called "upstream"?

> After a release branch is announced, only serious bug fixes are
>   included in the release branch. If possible these bug fixes are first
>   merged into master and then cherry-picked into the release branch.
>   This way you can't forget to cherry-pick them into master and
>   encounter the same bug on subsequent releases. This is called an
>   'upstream first' policy that is also practiced by Google and Red Hat

[from gitlab flow docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/gitlab_flow.html)

Comment: Your quoted paragraph explains **exactly** what *upstream first policy* means. It's in the entire text before the final sentence. Whether it's practiced or not is a polling question (how many people use this?) and therefore is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In software development, upstream refers to a direction toward the original authors or maintainers of software that is distributed as source code, and is a qualification of either a bug or a patch. For example, a patch sent upstream is offered to the original authors or maintainers of the software. If accepted, the authors or maintainers will include the patch in their software, either immediately or in a future release. If rejected, the person who submitted the patch will have to maintain his or her own distribution of the author's software.
>
> Upstream development allows other distributions to benefit from it when they pick up the future release.
>
> The term also pertains to bugs; responsibility for a bug is said to lie upstream when it is not caused through the distribution's porting and integration efforts.

Source: [Wikipedia - Upstream (software development)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstream_(software_development))